# This account is scheduled to be deleted 11 mins ago

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts

I'm about to delete my account, the 24 hours period is over and now it says on my user page:

> This account is scheduled to be deleted 11 mins ago

[image: screenshot of the message]

What does this mean?

- Is this some kind of extra safety net, just in case someone changes their mind right after those 24 hours?
- Maybe technical reasons?
- A bug?

Comment: I hope that a moderator can make an exception in this case and accept the first correct answer, as I, by the nature of this question, probably can't do that myself.

Comment: Mods can't mark answers accepted on your behalf, but a single upvote on an answer means the question is considered 'answered' (i.e. won't show on the 'unanswered' tab and is immune to the Community user auto-bump script), so don't worry about it too much. :)

Comment: Goodbye, bearb001. We'll miss your helpful minecraft-commands answers.

Answer (score 6):

There is probably a small timing difference when an account is scheduled for deletion, vs when the script that processes deleted accounts actually runs.

It seems to have run now, in any case.

https://shouldiblamecaching.com/